# React to built-in alarm clock

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications

I have heard that there isn't a specific alarm API for Apple's built-in alarm clock app, but is there a way to set up a listener to that specific alarm going off?

In my case I want to send a user notification x amount of minutes after an alarm goes off on the built in alarm clock app.

Comment: No, there is no API of any kind related to the alarms of the stock Clock app.